# what was Cain's mark given by God?

Tags: cain

Cain was cursed by God for killing his younger brother. But what was the mark that God gave Cain? Are there new discoveries/theories about this mark?

> And the LORD said unto him, Therefore whosoever slayeth Cain, vengeance shall be taken on him sevenfold. And the LORD set a mark upon Cain, lest any finding him should kill him.  [Genesis 4:15 KJV.]

Comment: I have edited your question just to show the relevant text and to demonstrate to you how to highlight and present such quotations. Since the site specifically deals with the text of scripture it is best to actually quote the verse of interest as the site does not discuss biblical 'topics' as such, but hermeneutically examines the text of scripture itself.

Comment: Related [What mark did the Lord put on Cain ... etc](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/what-mark-did-the-lord-put-on-cain-so-no-one-would-kill-him/20899#20899)